# COCOS2D for iOS - CCMoveTo does not work...?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

sorry, my english level is very low.

my code...

```
CCNode *A = [self getChildByTag:kATag];
CCNode *B = [self getChildByTag:kBTag];

CCMoveTo *MoveAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:A.position.x, 0];

[A runAction:[[MoveAction]copy];
[B runAction:[[MoveAction]copy];
```

B sprite is moved.
but A sprite does Not Move.

so, i added

```
[A stopAllActions];
[A runAction:[[MoveAction]copy];
[B runAction:[[MoveAction]copy];
```

but does not work.

```
[A setVisible:NO]
```

so, this code is work. 
Sprite A is Hide.

Why CCMoveTO does not work????

Answer (score 2):

`CCMoveTo` was deprecated in `V3`, now `CCActionMoveTo` is used.

Try this:

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
CGPoint convertedLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

CCActionMoveTo *MoveAction = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:convertedLocation];

[A runAction:[[MoveAction]copy];
[B runAction:[[MoveAction]copy];
```

Comment: when this question was asked (3 years ago) , OP's formulation was correct. @SirNod's answer is correct as it may, whilst your merely confuses the issue. You are mixing syntax from version 2 and version 3 (getChildByTag v2, CCActionMoveTo v3) AND also mixing on a single line of code : if CCMoveTo exists , surely CCActionMoveTo does not. this does not compile either now or then. -1

Comment: Before making claims such as "if CCMoveTo exists, surely CCActionMoveTo does not", you should really at least make an effort to check the documentation. That being said, the code does compile after edit. SirNod's doesn't work in V3, which is why I provided the updated code.

If you know the answer, why not provide it instead of being immature?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
CMoveTo *MoveAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:CGPointMake(A.position.x, 0)];
```

Also, what is the A's Y position? If it is 0, then it won't move anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
CCNode *A = [self getChildByTag:kATag];
CCNode *B = [self getChildByTag:kBTag];

CCMoveTo *MoveActionA = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:A.position.x+10, 0];
CCMoveTo *MoveActionB = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:B.position.x+10, 0];

[A runAction:MoveActionA];
[B runAction:MoveActionB];
```

- Each CCNode must have its own CCAction object. You can't use a single CCAction for multiple CCNodes.
- Double check that the position you are moving to is correct. In your code it is possible to you were moving it to its current position.
- There was no need for the "copy" to run the action.